# Phpmyadmin stops connecting to mysql server after being up for a few months

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I have a docker container running MySQL and another docker container running phpmyadmin.  Both containers are running on my Ubuntu server.

Normally I can log into MySQL without problems thru phpmyadmin.  However, this has happened several times in the past, that phpmyadmin runs into some issue and says:

```
"Cannot log in to the MySQL server" and 
"mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory".
```

The funny thing is this happens at seemingly random times before giving this error.  One time it worked for 4 months before giving this error message, another time it was 1 month, another time it was 3 months.  There didn't seem to be any periodic or specific amount of time before it gave me this error.

I also checked the mysql container and it's still up and running and when I log into it (mysql container), I can access my db and see all the data and tables in it.

When I start the phpmyadmin container, I use this command.  There is no config.user.inc.php file in /etc/phpmyadmin and it works for a few months.

```
docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql_db_server:db -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin
```

I found some stackoverflow questions that were similar to my issue but doing what is suggested doesn't work.

One person said to edit the config.user.inc.php file and change the host to 127.0.0.1.  I used the config.sample.php as my template for config.user.inc.php.  In my config.user.inc.php file, I added

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

I then mounted a volume on my local linux server to map to /etc/phpmyadmin on the container such that when we started the container, it would use the config file.  I ran:

```
docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql_db_server:db -p 8080:80 -v /local/dir/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php phpmyadmin
```

However, this is worse than when I run the docker command without the volume because using the config.user.inc.php file makes me run into the error immediately.  It's almost if the config.sample.inc.php file was misconfigured

The work around for me is to wait for phpmyadmin to give me the error, stop and kill the phpmyadmin container, then start a new one.  However, if I can get it to work right off the bat and not run into this error, that would be most ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after debugging a little, I believe there's a problem with the VM that's running the docker images.  I created another VM with the same OS (Ubuntu 16.04) running the same docker images and phpmyadmin is still connected to mysql, even after 5 months.  I don't know exactly what's wrong but rather than waste time debugging, I think migrating over to a new VM seems to be what needs to be done next.